# How to get Twitter Fabric Key

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm developing an App using Ionic.

I want to add get [twitter-connect-plugin](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin#get-a-fabric-api-key) but to install it I must provide a Fabric Key.

I go to [Fabric.io](https://fabric.io/settings/organizations/) but it force me to download an extension for my IDEs.

Why I need a Fabric Key? Is there a way to get a Fabric Key without installing these plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. The API key is used to help identify apps and the data that flows into Fabric for them - such as crash reports or analytics for Answers. For example, a crash report for your app using a specific bundle id A, API key B and platform D, would be identified differently then bundle id A, API key C and platform D. This is helpful when developers want debug data to not be in the same grouping as production app data.

If you can't or don't want to use the IDE plugin, then you can go through the web onboarding here: https://fabric.io/kits

One thing to note is that Ionic based apps are not officially supported.

Comment: This is not the answer of "How to get Twitter Fabric Key?" question